# I have to call php variable in Javascript but in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

how can I place PHP variable in a JavaScript variable which is in a string .In below example I am showing few lines where I call PHP variable in script. I put all the html in $dom and then echo the page .

```
$dom.= 'var loop="<? echo $loop_from_php; ?>"';
$dom.= 'var array="<? echo json_encode($winner_ids); ?>"';
echo $dom;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

It looks be next:

```
$dom.= 'var loop="' . $loop_from_php . '";';
$dom.= 'var array=' . json_encode($winner_ids) . ';';
echo $dom;
```

Comment: The value of `array` shouldn't be quoted